# function for calculate the rms average in matlab

Tags: matlab, mat

I have the equation shown below to calculate the average of a number of numbers stored in a vector.
I would like to know how I could put this function in matlab, since it is difficult for me to translate it because I do not understand the summation part nor the | x_n | ^ 2 part

equation:

[image: formule]

Comment: I'd be happy to help. Have you tried to attempt it? Please post any attempts so we can see the approach you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Handling Summations in MATLAB

Summations can be done using the `sum()` function or using a for-loop and iteratively adding. Assuming that you understand mathematically the process of calculating, below are some methods that translate this to MATLAB code.

### Method 1: Using Element-Wise Operations

Here vector `x` is squared (raised to the exponent 2) element-wise. This means each element in vector `x` is taken to the power of 2. The portion of code that does the squaring is `abs(x).^2`. Element-wise operations can are denoted by the `.` preceding the operation. In this case, the operation is multiplication, `*` configured to element-wise multiplication becomes `.*`.

```
%Random vector of integers%
x = round(100*rand(1,100));

N = length(x);
x_RMS = sqrt((1/N)*sum(abs(x).^2));
x_RMS
```

---

### Method 2: Using a For-Loop

Using a for-loop breaks the equation down into iterative steps that simulate the summation process. Here each value in vector `x` is squared and added to a variable called the `Accumulator` that keeps a running total of the summation as it's being iteratively calculated.

```
%Random vector of integers%
x = round(100*rand(1,100));

N = length(x);
Accumulator = 0;
for n = 1: N
   Accumulator = Accumulator + abs(x(n))^2; 
end

x_RMS = sqrt((1/N)*Accumulator);
x_RMS
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in calculating the RMS value, you don't need to implement the RMS function yourself, you can instead use the built-in function:

```
help rms

rms    Root mean squared value.
    For vectors, rms(X) is the root mean squared value in X. ...
```

If your input is a vector `x`, you might do something like

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 12, 5, 6]
y = rms(x)
```

If instead you are trying to implement the function yourself, take a look at the `rms` source code by typing the following into the command window

```
open rms
```

In the source file there should be two cases depending on the number of inputs (and maybe on the version of Matlab you are using).